# Getting error mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/rabbitmq’: Permission denied when creating Kubernetes pod of Rabbitmq

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

While learning Kubernetes going by the book Kubernetes for developer, I am stuck at this point now.

I am trying to start Rabbitmq pod but but after lot of troubleshooting I have managed to get to this point but do not get clue where do I fix to get rid of the permission denied error.

```
# kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-56c67d8d7d-s8vp5   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m40s
```

if I look at the logs of this contianer thats where I found:

```
# kubectl logs  rabbitmq-56c67d8d7d-s8vp5
 21:22:58.49 
 21:22:58.50 Welcome to the Bitnami rabbitmq container
 21:22:58.51 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq
 21:22:58.51 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-rabbitmq/issues
 21:22:58.52 Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com
 21:22:58.52 
 21:22:58.52 INFO  ==> ** Starting RabbitMQ setup **
 21:22:58.54 INFO  ==> Validating settings in RABBITMQ_* env vars..
 21:22:58.56 INFO  ==> Initializing RabbitMQ...
 21:22:58.57 INFO  ==> Generating random cookie
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/bitnami/rabbitmq’: Permission denied
```

Here is my **rabbitmq-deployment.yml**

```
---
# EXPORT SERVICE INTERFACE
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: message-queue
    labels:
      app: rabbitmq
      role: master
      tier: queue
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
      app: rabbitmq
      role: master
      tier: queue
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
      role: master
      tier: queue
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         app: rabbitmq
         role: master
         tier: queue
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        boardType: x86vm
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: bitnami-rabbitmq-config
        ports:
        - name: queue
          containerPort: 5672
        - name: queue-mgmt
          containerPort: 15672
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - rabbitmqctl
            - status
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          failureThreshold: 6
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - rabbitmqctl
            - status
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rabbitmq-storage
          mountPath: /bitnami
      volumes:
      - name: rabbitmq-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: rabbitmq-pv-claim
```

This is the **rabbitmq-storage-class.yml**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-storage-class
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

and **persistant-volume.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /bitnami
```

Logs:

```
# kubectl describe pods rabbitmq-5f7f787479-fpg6g
Name:         rabbitmq-5f7f787479-fpg6g
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         kube-worker-vm2/192.168.1.36
Start Time:   Mon, 03 May 2021 12:29:17 +0100
Labels:       app=rabbitmq
              pod-template-hash=5f7f787479
              role=master
              tier=queue
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.222.4/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.222.4/32
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.222.4
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.222.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/rabbitmq-5f7f787479
Containers:
  rabbitmq:
    Container ID:   docker://bbdbb9c5d4b6737519d3dcf4bdda242a7fe904f2336334afe686e9b204fd6d5c
    Image:          bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bitnami/rabbitmq@sha256:8b6057997b74ebc81e934dd6c94e9da745635faa2d79b382cfda27b9176e0e6d
    Ports:          5672/TCP, 15672/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Mon, 03 May 2021 12:30:48 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 03 May 2021 12:30:48 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Liveness:       exec [rabbitmqctl status] delay=120s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [rabbitmqctl status] delay=10s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      bitnami-rabbitmq-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:               <none>
    Mounts:
      /bitnami from rabbitmq-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4qmxr (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  rabbitmq-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  rabbitmq-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-4qmxr:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4qmxr
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  boardType=x86vm
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m20s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/rabbitmq-5f7f787479-fpg6g to kube-worker-vm2
  Normal   Created    96s (x4 over 2m18s)   kubelet            Created container rabbitmq
  Normal   Started    95s (x4 over 2m17s)   kubelet            Started container rabbitmq
  Warning 

 BackOff    65s (x12 over 2m16s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled     50s (x5 over 2m18s)   kubelet            Container image "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7" already present on machine
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating an image, the image creator often chooses to use a user other than root to run the process. This is the case for your image, and the user does not have write permissions on the `/bitnami` directory. You can verify this by commenting out the volume.

To fix the issue, you need to set a security contect for your pod: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod

Not sure about the exact syntax, but something like this should do the trick:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001 # the userid that is used in the image
  nodeSelector:
    boardType: x86vm
  containers:
  - name: rabbitmq
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.7
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: bitnami-rabbitmq-config
```

This makes the directory writeable by the user in the image.

Another thing: A deployment is for stateless services by design. If you have state to keep, always use a statefulset. It's very similiar to a deployment from a configuration point of view, but Kubernetes treats it very differently. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrxr-7rjkvM for good explanation.

Comment: I tried but that didn't help. I have also added `kubectl describe ` result.

Answer (score 0):

As per bitnami documentation, it depends on the kubernetes distribution
Quote from documentation

Adjust permissions of persistent volume mountpoint
As the image run as non-root by default, it is necessary to adjust the ownership of the persistent volume so that the container can write data into it.

By default, the chart is configured to use Kubernetes Security Context to automatically change the ownership of the volume. However, this feature does not work in all Kubernetes distributions. As an alternative, this chart supports using an initContainer to change the ownership of the volume before mounting it in the final destination.

You can enable this initContainer by setting **volumePermissions.enabled to true.**